# Change Gentelella color scheme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gentelella

Can someone help me how to change Gentelella color scheme. Specially the sidebar, what classes I need to include in my CSS.

Thank you.

Comment: check this link https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin/wiki/How-to-change-color-scheme

Comment: that is a different admin template. @AjeetChoudhary

Comment: You could inspect the current CSS settings and files by using the F12 tools.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly these 2 tags are related to sidebar
(i hope you are referring to this template https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html)

```
.left_col {
    background: *YourColor*;
}

.nav_title {
    background: *YourColor*;
}
```

but it is better to add your own class and modify it with your interest. Inspect the rest of child elements (tag) with a browser (F12) and find related tags and do the same.